# Maven generates old and unwanted RichFaces jars

Tags: eclipse, jsf, maven

I have a JSF 2.0 project and when I run 'mvn package' from eclipse (right click on the pom file and run) I get the war file with older versions of the richfaces jars along with the latest jars as shown in the image below.

[image]

pom.xml:

```
<properties>  
    <org.richfaces.bom.version>4.3.4.Final</org.richfaces.bom.version>  
</properties> 


<dependencies>
    <!-- Mojarra implementation of JSF spec 2.2 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.richfaces</groupId>  
        <artifactId>richfaces-bom</artifactId>  
        <version>${org.richfaces.bom.version}</version>  
        <scope>import</scope>  
        <type>pom</type>  
    </dependency>
    <dependency>  
       <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>  
       <artifactId>richfaces-components-ui</artifactId>  
        <version>${org.richfaces.bom.version}</version>  
   </dependency>  
   <dependency>  
       <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>  
       <artifactId>richfaces-core-impl</artifactId>  
        <version>${org.richfaces.bom.version}</version>  
   </dependency> 
</dependencies>
```

How can I fix this?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest you to install maven outside of eclipse and try to run *'mvn package'* from command line and see if you encounter the same problem in this way as well.

You may also create a *'New Launch Configuration'* in eclipse for running *mvn package* from inside eclipse.  To do this, right click on the pom.xml file > Run as > Run configuration ...
Hit *'New launch configuration'*.  This will take care of any mis-configuration you might have done inadvertently in your earlier launch configuration.